# String concat() return type

Tags: java, string

while doing brush up my knowledge seems the below code & surprised how it works. If anybody know, explain it.

```
class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        String s1 = "abc";
        s1.concat("ef");
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
abc
```

Expected Output:

```
compile time error since concat() return type is string & it is not returned.
```

Comment: java does flag error if you ignore the value returned by a method. it will probably be indicated as a warning on your ide

Comment: radhik, it is returned, you just don't assign the returned value.

Comment: "it is not returned" - what makes you think so? It _is_ returned but not used. That's a potential bug for sure but not an error. Calling a method but not using the returned data is totally ok - unless you're calling it to get that data, in which case the bug would be that the intended use of the method doesn't match the actual use - but that's something the compiler can't know.

Comment: Why do you expect a compile time error from that code? As for why you get the actual output, just read the first few lines of the official javadoc of the String class: "Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created." So s1 will never change without you assigning new Strings to it with "="

Comment: @AniketSahrawat which is not really related to the question. he assumes that, since he doesn't assign the result to a variable, an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: Lucky, you are allowed to ignore the returned value of a method. (I don't believe we can prove that with the JLS since it would be strange to be forced that way) You are responsible to use it or not. In your case of course, ignoring it is not an option since `String` are immutable, ignoring it is the same as not calling the method at all since no update can be done on a `String` instance.

Comment: My focus point here is, s1.concat("ef"); If anyone refer java.lang.String class, we could see return type of concat() is string. In java, if we write any user defined method without return type obviously it will throw compile time error. But, in this case it is not thrown. Why it is not thrown any error/exception?

Comment: @radhik, `s1.concat()` is not "without a return type", and nothing you can do in your code (short of reflection, bytecode manipulation, etc.) will ever cause it to not have a return type. As Java is a strongly typed language, the return type of the method is defined at the time of method definition, and nothing you do while calling the method can affect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a method, you don't specify any return type, you can specify the variable in which you want to store the returned value specified by the method declaration basicly like :

```
public String concat(String s){
     return this.value + s;
}
```

When you call a method :

```
"foo".concat("bar"); //return "foobar"
```

The `String` instance with the value "foobar" will be returned, but you are not attributing it to any variable, it is allowed even if in your case, it doesn't make sense since the result of that concatenation will be lost.

Now, if you are trying to explain that you can't not have a method like :

```
public String concat(String s){
     this.value + s;
}
```

You are correct, you can't implement a method declared with a return type but not returning anything. It will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The String object type is immutable. For getting the concatenated value you must do this:

```
String s1 = "abc";
s1 = s1.concat("ef");
```

You don't get a compile time error because it is not necessary to store into a variable the returned value of the concatenation.